# How to use raw_input to assign a variable number of inputs?

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
a, b, c = raw_input().split()
```

User inputs:

```
1
2
3
4
```

How do I make it so that both 3 and 4 get assigned to variable c?
Note that I can only use one raw_input call, and the user input cannot be changed.

Edit: I cannot change what the user inputs, and the user's input is always 4 (or more) numbers at a time. The first two numbers can get assigned to a and b. The remaining numbers need to all get assigned to variable c as a tuple, list, or other. Basically I'm asking if there's a simple way like *args to do this.

Comment: What if you typed `1 2 3,4`?

Comment: I cannot change what the user inputs, and the user's input is always 4 (or more) numbers at a time. The first two numbers get assigned to a and b. The remaining numbers need to all get assigned to variable c as a tuple, list, or other. Basically I'm asking if there's a simple way like *args to do this.

Comment: @Renegade `args=raw_input().split();a,b=args[:2];c=args[2:]`. Or you can use what @cricket_007 said and convert `c` from string to list later.

Comment: @Abhishek Bhatia Thanks, exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: It's too bad that you are using Python 2.  In Python 3, it is as simple as `a, b, *c = raw_input().split()`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
args = raw_input().split()
a, b, c = args[0], args[1], args[2:]
```

Your `c` will contain the remaining inputs as a list.